# ¿Como obtener los datos desde otra colección?

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una colección llamada **usuario** el cual tiene la siguiente estructura.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4ae50fbdc1cd6351dab49f"),
    "nombre" : "usuario1",
    "Correo" : "correo1@gmail.com",
    "playlist" : 
     [ 
        {
            "nombrePlay" : "play1",
            "descPlay" : "descPlay",
            "canciones" : 
            [ 
                ObjectId("5d4ae655bdc1cd6351dab4c5")
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Tengo una colección de **Canciones** con la siguiente estructura

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4ae655bdc1cd6351dab4c5"),
    "nombreCancion" : "cancion1",
    "detalleCancion" : "detalleCancion"
}
```

lo que intento es que cuando obtenga al `usuario1`
no solo me muestre la lista de `playlist` si no que tambien la descripción de la canción..

pero al hacer un `db.usuarios.find()` me regresa la misma estructura que mostrada al inicio
para insertar los datos me base en la siguiente parte de la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que usas MongoDB 3.2+ (espero que sí), para obtener los datos de una colección sobre otra mediante la referencia que has indicado, debes usar un proceso de [Agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html), el cual debe constar de dos etapas:

1. Etapa [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/): Durante esta etapa se realiza un filtro para permitir sólo los documentos que *coincidan* con el filtro dado. En tu caso particular el filtro sería: `{"nombre": "usuario1"}`. De esta forma los documentos devueltos serán todos aquellos cuyo campo nombre coincida con el filtro.
2. Etapa [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#lookup-aggregation): Durante esta etapa se realiza una *búsqueda* (sobre la misma base de datos), de los elementos de otra colección que se corresponden con el valor guardado como referencia en la colección sobre la que se aplica la agregación. Los parámetros que se usan en esta etapa son:

   - `from`: Indica la colección desde la que se extraerán los datos referenciados. En tu caso es `canciones`.
   - `localField`: Indica el campo de la colección (sobre la que se aplica la agregación), que contiene las referencias a otra colección. En tu caso, el campo local es `playlist.canciones`.
   - `foreignField`: Indica el campo (de la colección indicada en `from`) que coincide con la referencia indicada en `localField`. En tu caso el campo es `_id`, ya que has guardado como referencia los valores de `_id` de los documentos de la colección `canciones`.
   - `as`: Especifica el nombre del nuevo `Array` que contendrá los documentos de la colección (especificada en `from`) con los datos solicitados. Si el campo no existe, el mismo será añadido al resultado, en cambio si el mismo existe, será reemplazado con los datos solicitados. En tu caso puedes sobre escribir el campo `playlist.canciones`.

Así tu consulta puede quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
db.usuarios.aggregate([
  {$match: {nombre: "usuario1"}},
  {$lookup: {
    from: "canciones",
    localField: "playlist.canciones",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "playlist.canciones"
  }}
]);
```

El resultado obtenido puede verse de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e5bf286eca88ff939304c"),
    "nombre" : "usuario1",
    "correo" : "correo1@gmail.com",
    "playlist" : {
        "nombrePlay" : "play1",
        "descPlay" : "descPlay",
        "canciones" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e5bf286eca88ff9393049"),
                "nombreCancion" : "cancion1",
                "detalleCancion" : "detalle1"
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e5bf286eca88ff939304a"),
                "nombreCancion" : "cancion2",
                "detalleCancion" : "detalle2"
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d6e5bf286eca88ff939304b"),
                "nombreCancion" : "cancion3",
                "detalleCancion" : "detalle3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Espero que esto te aclare la duda y te ayude a resolver el problema.

**Nota**

- El resultado devuelto será un `Array` con los documentos procesados.
- La etapa `$lookup` tiene una restricción sobre colecciones fragmentadas (`sharded`). Puedes leer más en [Sharded Collection Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-sharded-collections)

Comment: Funciono perfectamente, Gracias.